# How to change the height of a horizontalHeader (QTableWidget)

Tags: qt4, qtableview, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget and I want to change the size of the horizontalHeaders. But there is only a function to set the width. But how do you change the height? Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the docs (I don't have Qt on my current system), you can get the `QTableWidgetItem` from `horizontalHeaderItem` and then call the `setSizeHint(QSize)` function to give it a size which contains a height property.

Comment: Thank you very much, don't know how I didn't see that.

Comment: I forgot to say, that I needed to set horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents) too